# != not working as expected in .tag file

Tags: jsp, el, jsp-tags

In a project in which I am working, there are .tag files,

```
<%@ attribute name="stepNumber" required="true" description="step number"%>
<c:if test="${stepNumber != 4}">
    <div> Some text </div>
</c:if>
```

the above `c:if` condition results in true even when stepNumber is `eq` to 4.
Why?
If I change the code to & when I am in step4 of the application

```
 <c:if test="${stepNumber == 5}">
        <div> Some text </div>
 </c:if>
```

or

```
<c:if test="${stepNumber} != '4'">
    <div> Some text </div>
</c:if>
```

It works as expected. Why not for `!=`    ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not explicitly specify a type for the attribute then it defaults to java.lang.String.

```
<%@ attribute name="stepNumber" required="true" description="step number"%>
```

Therefore using

`<x:MyTag stepNumber="4" />`

will result in `stepNumber` being a String.

Here you are testing a String against an int so this will always be false.

```
   <c:if test="${stepNumber != 4}">
```

For String comparison use:

```
<c:if test="${stepNumber} != '4'">
```

You can explicitly specify the type if you are working with numbers:

```
<%@ attribute name="stepNumber" required="true" description="step number" type="java.lang.Integer" %>

<c:if test="${stepNumber != 4}">
```